# Tuning JavaVM on AWS/EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance-tuning, java

there's some specific tuning JVM configuration for AmazonWS/EC2 building blocks (small, large...)?

Somebody have suggestions for tuning JVM running on these machine profiles?

Regards,

And Past

Answer (score 1):

This is highly application specific, and really has little to do with EC2 specifically.  The only difference on EC2 versus a regular server is that performance is not guaranteed--so pick some safe values and load test.

That being said, here are a few links to get you started:

- http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/22/performance-tuning-jvm-running-tomcat
- http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=63276

But you'll get much better mileage if you find something specific to your Java application.

Comment: We have a custom JVM configuration that works fine on physical machines.

But, when we deploy these same options on EC2 instances, it works different. I think that configure just the application level, all issues are not solved, considering, as you said, that performance is not guaranteed.

We need something new about performance over a shared CPU. These links are well known, already, when we need to optimize physical machines

Comment: Well, like I said, you'll need to set values and test them on EC2.  What you want to look for is average performance--since you're going to see a lot of fluctuations, you'll need to figure out how many users you can expect EC2 to safely handle, and that requires load testing.